# How to implement binary search on function in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I've got a situation in C++ where I have a costly sub-problem: nearly a minute. Further, this subproblem--`bool f(x)`--gets longer as `x` ranges from [1,n].

On the range of [1,n], there is a point `1<j<n, f(j) = true` such that `f(k), k < j` is **always false**...and `f(m), j < m` is **always true**.

I need to find that point.

---

The way I need to do it is with **binary search** starting at `x=1` (so that it never even touches the time consuming region, where x is close to n).

---

Right now, I am manually slogging through a binary search implementation where I start at a minimum value for a function (so, `f(1)`, which is false).  Then I double the input value until I reach a state where `f(x) is happy` (true).  This part is no big deal.  I can do it manually fine.

Next, I want to binary search on the range [x/2,x] for the **first** value where `f(x) = true` (noting that `f(x/2)` must equal false, since `f(1) = false`...and I need to do it without making any mistakes. And *this* is where things are getting a little hairy.

---

So I have a creeping suspicion that C++ has this already implemented, but I am new to C++, and have limited experience with the libraries.  I am currently looking at binary search, but I don't see a way to bin search for the actual point at which all values of a function change from false to true.

Rather, it seems to be greedy: it would just grab the first `true` it finds, rather than the minimum `true`.

How would I do this in C++?

---

The inputs of my search function would be as follows:

```
std::vector<int> range(max);
for (int j = 0; j < max; j++){
    range[j] = j;
}

std::some_search_function(range.begin(),range.end(),f(int value))
```

where `f(...)` is the boolean function from before...

And it needs to have the properties of what I am describing: start from the first value in the item it is searching, and return the earliest item where `f(...)` is satisfied...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement a custom iterator that "points" to true or false depending on the index it represents and use [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) function to find the first `true` value.